# Time complexity of a non-trivial recursive function

Tags: java, recursion, time-complexity

I wrote a recursive function that takes an array of positive integers (> 0) (`denominations`) and an integer value (`amount`) and returns the number of ways it is possible to obtain the value using only the integers in the array. So for example, the array of integers can be thought of as change and the integer value as the amount of money you have to pay. And the function returns the number of ways you can pay the cashier. For example:

`amount` = 4 and `denominations` = [1,2,3,4]

This should return `5`

I have tested my function and it works fine. When calling the function, the arguments `acc` and `index` are passed as 0. Here is the function:

```
public int count_number_of_ways(int amount, int acc, int index,  int[] denominations) {

        if (acc > amount) return 0;

        if (amount == acc) return 1;


        int len = denominations.length;
        int count = 0;

        while (acc < amount) {


            for (int i = index + 1; i < len; i++) {


                count += count_number_of_ways(amount, acc + denominations[i], i, denominations);


            }

            acc += denominations[index];

            if (acc > amount) return count + 0;

            if (acc == amount) return count + 1;

        }

        return count + 0;


}
```

I tried to compute the time complexity of this function but hit a brick wall. The recursive call is inside a for loop which is inside a while loop and that made things confusing for me. Could anyone help me determine the time complexity for this function ?

Comment: I don't think you have fully tested code. For instance it works wrong with `amount` = 6 and `denominations` = [1,2,3].

Comment: @rsutormin Thank you for pointing that out. I edited the code. Should work now.

Comment: If you don't restrict your denominations to be _positive_ integers your algorithm will never stop (i.e. if one is 0 or negative your core loop never ends).

Comment: @MichaelAnderson  The denominations are supposed to be positive integers. I will add that in.

Comment: Note that your program will be much more efficient if you use dynamic programming (bottom-up recursion) instead, so as to eliminate the large proportion of duplicate recursive calls. As a nice side-benefit, it will also be easier to calculate the complexity then.

Comment: @ruakh Noted. Will try to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking in worst case you will spend time proportional to (`amount`/`denominations[0]`) * (`amount`/`denominations[1]`) * ... * (`amount`/`denominations[n]`), where n - number of denominations.

This is because you look over all sets of counts for each of your denominations. And maximum count for particular denomination number `i` is `amount`/`denominations[i]`.

In real case you stop the process earlier but I don't think it changes O((amount/geometric_average_denomination)^n).

It's possible to avoid exponential time though. For that you can use dynamic programming approach. Here is my version of your algorithm requiring O(amount * n) time:

```
public static int count_number_of_ways(int amount, int index, Integer[][] cache, int[] denominations) {
    if (cache == null)
        cache = new Integer[denominations.length][amount + 1];
    if (amount == 0) {
        int ret = 1;
        cache[index][amount] = ret;
        return ret;
    }
    if (cache[index][amount] != null) {
        return cache[index][amount];
    }
    int ret = 0;
    if (index + 1 < denominations.length)
        ret += count_number_of_ways(amount, index + 1, cache, denominations);
    if (amount >= denominations[index])
        ret += count_number_of_ways(amount - denominations[index], index, cache, denominations);
    cache[index][amount] = ret;
    return ret;
}
```

The idea is to fill matrix of size [n][amount] where each element (i,j) is number of solutions for amount=j using subset of denominations with indexes>=i. You fill each element of this `cache` matrix only once and reuse it later if it's defined already.

Use it like:

```
int ret = count_number_of_ways(amount, 0, null, denominations)
```

Comment: Thought about it and this seems to be in the right ball park. I am still not a 100 % sure though.  But I think for all practical purposes , the important thing to take away is that the complexity is exponential.

Comment: @Haider, I updated my answer with non-exp solution (using memory though but you didn't discuss memory limitations).